# How to give default values for the SUM() and COUNT() if no data exist in MySQL query which uses GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql

I am using following query which works fine for me except one problem

```
SELECT f.period                            AS month,
       SUM(p.revenue * ((100-q.rate)/100)) AS revenue,
       COUNT(DISTINCTq.label)              AS tot_stmt 
FROM files f, reports p, rates q,albums a
WHERE f.period IN ('2010-06-01','2010-05-01','2010-04-01','2010-03-01') 
  AND f.period_closed = TRUE
  AND q.period = f.period
  AND a.id = q.album_id
  AND p.file_id = f.id
  AND p.upc = a.upc
  AND p.revenue IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month DESC;
```

O/P =>

> month             revenue    
>   tot_stmt
>
> 2010-06-01      10.00             2
>
>  2010-05-01      340.47        2

I want result like following:

> month             revenue    
>   tot_stmt
>
> 2010-06-01      10.00             2
>
>  2010-05-01      340.47        2 
> 2010-04-01      0.00       
>        0 
>  2010-03-01      0.00   
>         0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT f.period                                       AS month,
       IFNULL(SUM(p.revenue * ((100-q.rate)/100)), 0) AS revenue,
       COUNT(DISTINCT q.label)                        AS tot_stmt 
FROM files f 
     LEFT JOIN reports p ON f.id = p.file_id
     LEFT JOIN rates q ON f.period = q.period
     LEFT JOIN albums a ON q.album_id = a.id AND p.upc = a.upc
WHERE f.period IN ('2010-06-01','2010-05-01','2010-04-01','2010-03-01') 
  AND f.period_closed = TRUE
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month DESC;
```

#### Explanations:

- rewritten the conditions to have `JOIN` clauses
- `COUNT(column)` returns `0` if all aggregated records have value
  `NULL` in that column
- `SUM(column)` returns `NULL` if all aggregated records have value
  `NULL` in that column
- you also need to allow `p.revenue` to be `NULL` (dropped that
  criteria)

---

#### Note

You don't seem to be getting anything from the albums table so you can take it out.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a helper table with the information you need. The helper table will hold months you are referring to:

### month

2010-06-01
2010-05-01
2010-04-01
2010-03-01

Once you have that table, you can **left outer join** to it, and use **isnull** function to populate default values you want.

Something like:

```
SELECT f.period as month, 
       sum(p.revenue * ((100-q.rate)/100)) as revenue, 
       count(distinct q.label) as tot_stmt  
  FROM (files f left outer join periods pers on f.period = pers.period), reports p, rates q,albums a 
 WHERE f.period in ('2010-06-01','2010-05-01','2010-04-01','2010-03-01')  
   AND f.period_closed = true 
   AND q.period = f.period 
   AND a.id = q.album_id 
   AND p.file_id = f.id 
   AND p.upc = a.upc 
   AND p.revenue is not null 
 GROUP BY month ORDER BY month DESC
```